# Select all rows in table A if another table B has rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database, I have two tables `A` and `B` and would like to select

- all rows in table `A` if table `B` has any rows
- no rows in table `A` if table `B` has no records

How should I write my SQL query?

Table `A` and `B` have columns `id` and `name`.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, and at your rep level, you should know about how to ask a clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check in the where-condition, if `b` has any rows:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b);
```

Comment: Well, it happens.. ^^ But still thanks for the appreciation